# Is a vehicle that's confined to one place still a vehicle?

Tags: terminology

Google's dictionary defines a vehicle as such:

> a thing used for transporting people or goods, especially on land, such as a car, lorry, or cart.

Now suppose that, for whatever reason, a vehicle can't satisfy its' definition. For example it's a bike that's secured by an indestructible lock no one has or ever will have key for. Can that bicycle still be called a bicycle in such case?

I'm absolutely sure that my question is far from being brilliant and original thought experiment. However I don't know where to look for an answer to my question.

EDIT:
Forgot to mention: the essence of my question goes beyond that particular vehicle example. I wanted to discuss if thing is and never will be able to fulfill its' destiny or meaning of existence could be fully qualified as that thing.

Comment: Language is, by all means, conventional, i.e. if "vehicle" is used to describe this object, it *is* a vehicle. Formal definitions can only cover "common" usage.

Comment: [A bike is a bike is a bike is a bike](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_is_a_rose_is_a_rose_is_a_rose).

Comment: Dictionaries do not define terms, they describe typical usage. The test for words is successful communication, if one can communicate their intent by calling permanently parked vehicle "vehicle" that is justification enough for using the word.

Comment: I voted to reopen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When something is defined we are giving it an explanation. We explain what the thing is. We imagine seeing that unknown thing in a class containing other things similar to it that we know something about.  That we know something about those things in general guides our expectations about how we can expect to relate to the specific thing at hand.  Knowing what something is can be very useful information.

Giving someone a definition, or a *what it is* explanation, provides someone with a *formal cause*.  A formal cause is one of Aristotle’s four causes, or explanations.  The other causes Aristotle came up with are the material cause (*what it is made out of*), the efficient cause (*how it got here*) and the final cause (*what is it for*).  Although Aristotle’s model of explanation is old, it is still relevant today.  Seeking a formal explanation or cause is valuable even to us today.  Most of us want to know what something is to help us relate to it.

When we provide someone with a formal cause or we state what that something is, we don’t *completely explain* what the thing is.  It would take too long to do so even if we knew what the complete explanation was.  Besides no one needs nor wants a complete explanation.  A complete explanation would put the specific thing into a general class of only one specific object.  So all of our explanations are incomplete.

Now let’s consider the bicycle example.

Suppose I am presented with a gift wrapped in a box.  My first question would be “What is it?”  I want the formal cause or explanation. Suppose the person giving me the present said, “It is a bicycle.” That person has given me a definition or a formal cause explaining what is in the box, but it is an incomplete explanation as are all explanations.  However, I have an idea of how I might be able to relate to that specific bicycle in the box because I know what bicycles are in general.  I might start wondering next, perhaps, what brand of bicycle?  I want a more detailed formal cause or explanation.

Suppose the giver at last tells me, “Yes, it is a bicycle, but don't get your hopes up.  It is really a bicycle bolted to a picture frame.” I now have more detailed information, a better formal cause of what is inside the box than I originally had.  I might be disappointed but I could still consider it a “bicycle” or I could switch the class the object belongs to thinking of it more like an "art object".

With that preliminary, I will try to answer the question:

> Can that bicycle still be called a bicycle in such case?

Yes, if you want. The formal cause is only an explanation that may be useful or not but is always incomplete. It is presented for your benefit. So, it could be a bicycle bolted to a frame if that best helps you relate to the bicycle or it could be an art object or it could be some of both.

Your question is not trivial. I hope the description above brought out two points:

1. Aristotle’s four causes are not obsolete.  To get more information on this with an emphasis on how modern these causes are and examples of the other three see the first half of Jack Sander’s *[Philosophy of Science Lecture 8: Scientific Explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-be4lH1_PI&t=1965s)*. To read more about Aristotle’s four causes see the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy entry, *[Aristotle’s Natural Philosophy](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/aristotle-natphil/)*:
2. Explanations are for our use and they are not complete. We sometimes think that if someone can *explain* something that they have given us a *complete explanation* of something.  As you can see in the example above, explanations are at best useful and always partial.

Answer (score 1):

1. If it isn't a bicycle, what is it ?
2. I think the definition should more accurately read : 'a thing of a type used for transporting people or goods, especially on land, such as a car, lorry, or cart'.
3. That would still leave your 'bicycle' a bicycle even if it were permanently locked out of use.
4. In general things should be defined in terms of their inherent qualities or capacities, so as to exclude conditions they might be in - contingent conditions - that block the exercise of those qualities or capacities.
5. It's a teasing question, glad you asked it.